# Coding an Excel function to fill in data gaps

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

In Excel, I currently have the following scatter-plot and its corresponding data set for one of the series:

[image]

I am attempting to create some kind of function that will enable me to interpolate points for the data gaps I currently have; the final aim is to create a smooth curve for the scatter-plot. Conceptually, the function I am trying to create is of the form:

Given:

```
n is an integer, x = 3 + 20n, y = 3 + 20(n + 1)    

=IF(B(3 + 20n) < cell < B(3 + 20(n+1)), add (y-x)/19 to previous value, do nothing)
```

That is, I have data points in columns 23, 43, 63,...etc. and am trying to fill in the gaps by adding a unique interval for each bin to the preceding cell. This interval is obtained by taking the lower and upper bounds of each bin and dividing by 19. In other words, each bin should look like this:

[image]

I have to do this for about 1000 cells, so to do this manually is tedious. Some guidance on how to create such a function that would enable me to execute everything in one go would be much appreciated; furthermore, if there is a better way of going about this, any information would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

First add an extra column. In this column you can use this formula:

```
=IF(MOD((ROW()-3),20)=0,B3,INDIRECT("B"&(QUOTIENT((ROW()-3),20)*20+3))+  
(INDIRECT("B"&(QUOTIENT((ROW()-3),20)*20+23))-INDIRECT("B"&  
(QUOTIENT((ROW()-3),20)*20+3)))/20*(ROW()-(QUOTIENT((ROW()-3),20)*20+3)))
```

How this formula works:

```
MOD(ROW()-3),20)=0
```

This checks if the row is 23,43,63,... If so it takes the adjacent cell, if not the next formula takes place:

```
INDIRECT("B"&(QUOTIENT((ROW()-3),20)*20+3))
```

This use the function indirect to calculate the adres of the first cell which row is less than the current row and also 23,43,63. It subtracts 3 from the current row and then divides it by 20 and rounds to a lower integer. Then it multiplies by 20 and adds 3 to get the right row number. This is then concatenated to the B to form the adres of the cell you want.

```
+(INDIRECT("B"&(QUOTIENT((ROW()-3),20)*20+23))-INDIRECT("B"&  
(QUOTIENT((ROW()-3),20)*20+3)))/20*(ROW()-(QUOTIENT((ROW()-3),20)*20+3))
```

This is simply an interpolation formula of the form:

```
 y_int = y_start + [(y_end-y_start)/(x_end-x_start)]*(x_int-x_start)
```

y_start is the one I explained above. Then you have y_end which is almost the same, only you add 23 instead of 3 to get the next value. Then you divide by 20, which is the difference between two following values. The x_int-x_start is the following formula:

```
ROW()-(QUOTIENT((ROW()-3),20)*20+3)
```

This takes the current row and subtracts the 23,43,63.. that is lower from it, by using the same method as I did to find y_start.